# cmake could not find a package configuration file provided by "OPENCV"

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I've built OpenCV v4.2 from source and installed it to `/usr/local`. `OPENCVConfig.cmake` file is in `/usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4` directory:

```
paul@paul-desktop:/usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4$ dir
OpenCVConfig.cmake  OpenCVConfig-version.cmake  OpenCVModules.cmake  OpenCVModules-release.cmake
```

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt` file with desperate attempts to satisfy `find_package`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.2)
project(af VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL 4)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4)
set(ENV{OPENCV_DIR} /usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4)
set(OPENCV_DIR /usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4)

find_package(OPENCV REQUIRED)

add_executable(af main.cpp)
```

which produces this error:

```
[build] CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package):
[build]   By not providing "FindOPENCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
[build]   asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OPENCV", but
[build]   CMake did not find one.
[build] 
[build]   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OPENCV" with any
[build]   of the following names:
[build] 
[build]     OPENCVConfig.cmake
[build]     opencv-config.cmake
[build] 
[build]   Add the installation prefix of "OPENCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
[build]   "OPENCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OPENCV"
[build]   provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
[build]   installed.
```

When I open `CMakeCache.txt` with `cmake-gui` and manually set `OPENCV_DIR` to `/usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4`, I'm getting the same error and `OPENCV_DIR` becomes
`OPENCV_DIR-NOTFOUND`.

What is happening here? It seems to me that I'm fulfilling the requirements listed in error message and any good advice I could find in answers to similar problems.

I'm not sure if it matters, but there `/usr/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake` belonging to a different version of OpenCV.

Comment: Package names are **case-sensitive**. Proper finding OpenCV is `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)`

Comment: I can't believe it got capitalized somewhere in the pipeline and my file search is case insensitive. If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package names are **case-sensitive**. And proper name of the OpenCV package for use in `find_package` is `OpenCV`, not `OPENCV`.

---

Actually, the only thing in CMake which *case-insensitive* is a macro/function name. **Everything** else is **case-sensitive**.

Some variables and files use *uppercase* or *lowercase* transformation of names. E.g. `OPENCV_DIR` variable uses a package name in *uppercase* and `opencv-config.cmake` file uses a package name in *lowercase*. But this doesn't deny case-sensitive aspects.